# Is Gauss's law still valid near the speed of light?

Tags: electromagnetic

When the speed of the charge is close to the speed of light, is Gauss's law still valid?
As far as I know, the invention of Gauss's law preceded the theory of special 
relativity, so if the answer is yes, then why is Gauss's law still valid when the speed of the charge is close to the speed of light?

Comment: This might be better in Physics.SE

Comment: Yes, unlike Coulomb's law, Gauss's law is relativistically consistent with the special theory. You need to focus on the divergence property of the electric field to see why, and it would take me a few pages of argument and probably the examination of both the differential and integral forms of the law to get there, but I'm sure you can find the development somewhere. It isn't all that complex.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Now I know that Gauss's law is relativistically consistent with the special theory. I will try to search the Internet for more information about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I finally have a moment to write out something.

### Intro

First off, it's better if I say a little something about Gauss's Law -- it's not just one law. There are two important versions, one for electricity and one for magnetism, and together they form up half of Maxwell's equations (which have a differential form and an integral form.) These two laws have very similar form and describe the net flux out of any closed surface.

The electricity version says that if you take any arbitrary volume shape and break it up into tiny areas small enough that you can treat them as "uncurved and flat", and if you then measure the magnitude of the electric flux perpendicular to that area, multiplying the tiny area by this magnitude, and sum up these product terms over the entire surface of the volume, then you will get a sum that is directly proportional to the total charge contained within that surface (no matter how that electric charge is arranged within the volume.) There will be a proportionality constant involved to convert the sum you get into the actual electric charge. But it's just one of those constants like **G** for the gravitational force acting between two particles of mass. (In this case, \$\epsilon_{_0}\$.)

The magnetism version says that if you take any arbitrary volume shape and break it up into tiny areas small enough that you can treat them as "uncurved and flat", and if you then measure the magnitude of the magnetic flux perpendicular to that area, multiplying the tiny area by this magnitude, and sum up these product terms over the entire surface of the volume, then you will get a sum that is always zero. This is why people say that magnetic monopoles don't exist. If they did, then the sum wouldn't be zero if a volume enclosed even one monopole and Gauss's magnetism law would be falsified. So far, that hasn't happened and so this lack of contradicting experimental evidence has been taken as a heavy weight against them. For enclosed magnetic dipoles (a simple case), some flux will point outward and some will point inward (opposite signs) and Gauss's magnetism law says the sum of all these product terms must result in zero.

The above is a simple statement. It's more nuanced, though. Suppose the volume encloses no electric charge. Then Gauss's electricity law says that the sum must be zero. But this must be true, even if there are lots of charges ***outside*** of the volume. So the laws say something more -- not only do they talk about what's inside an arbitrary volume of your choosing, they also imply you will get the same sum without regard to charges outside of the volume, too.

### Answer

I had mentioned in my comments that Gauss's Laws apply in relativistic situations. I'm going to avoid equations here and just refer to some concepts that may still be convincing without the math.

In Gauss's electricity law above, the volume is considered to be finite, with a surface vector field that is integrated. But we can shrink it to an infinitesimal volume, if we like. That process is called divergence and it generates the differential form of Gauss's electricity law. The scalar for each such infinitesimal volume will be either positive (a "source") or negative (a "sink.") This process of shrinking to an infinitesimal volume, or using divergence, develops what's called the "local" relationship between charge and field and has meaning at the same location and time, not at different locations and times, which is what avoids relativistic problems.

Put another way, divergence is co-ordinate-free, so it's computed values must be the same in ***any*** co-ordinate system. This is why I mentioned that divergence is the key to understanding why Gauss's electricity law works in relativistic situations. The differential form of Gauss's electricity law is inherently co-ordinate-free and that property makes it also relativistically correct.

(It does take a little extra work to then move from this differential form of Gauss's electricity law to the integral form, while continuing to demonstrate that the integral form must also be relativistically correct. That's the part that I didn't want to write out here and, instead, wanted you to find elsewhere. But you start by integrating the divergence with respect to the infinitesimal volumes and kind of "back yourself into" the integral form of Gauss's electricity law using only the rigorous application of mathematical axioms and logic to arrive there. The equations are few, but I'd need to write a paragraph or so for each, so I'd like to avoid it here.)

Hopefully, this is enough said to help you find some material that expands on what I just wrote.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my questions. It really helped me understand the situation.
I am very interested in electromagnetic theory, but I think that at present I only have a very superficial understanding of electromagnetic theory, so I really need to do more in-depth studying.

Comment: @TheOne It takes a little time to move ideas around and to let those ideas settle in. I have confidence that, if you keep at it, you will get it. Once you grasp them, they aren't actually that hard. It's funny like that. But our brains were NOT built for math. So it takes continual work.

Comment: @TheOne  Separately, keep in mind that theoretical ideas aren't necessarily mathematics. (Newton's idea of any two particles attracting each other isn't math... it's an idea.) Math allows us to take a specific situation and then rigorously derive from that situation, coupled with ideas from theory, a numerical formula. So the math follows the ideas, applied to specific situations. Some physicists think that the universe itself ***is*** mathematics that we experience only a part of -- but that's another argument for another time.

Comment: @TheOne I do, in this case, recommend that you read [The Feynman Lecture Series, Volume II](https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_toc.html) and start with the first chapter and work forward. Luckily, that book was heavily edited by Robert Leighton and Matthew Sands, without who I'm pretty sure it would be much more difficult to traverse. Feynman himself was obscure and skipped around a bit and was hard to follow during his actual lectures. Those two editors really pulled the best out of him and created something truly beautiful to read through. Just do it.

Comment: Thank you for sharing these lectures.
I just looked at it briefly now. I think this is a good, comprehensive and well-organized learning material. I will try to learn gradually.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my intuition behind Gauss's Law in integral form.
First a couple words about relativistic correctness (simplified view). Coulomb law is not relativistically correct since when either of the charges move, the law does not work any more. Gauss's Law is relativistically correct, since when charge moves the law still holds.

And here is why Gauss's Law in integral form still holds.
Imagine water source either in 2d or in 3d. I will use 2d since it is a bit easier. Fix circle around water source with some radius `r`. Now when water source is stationary, the amount of water (electric field) that gets through (crosses) our circle is fairly easy to compute, since field is uniform and directed radially. Gauss's law can be through as relation between amount of water and water source. Now when water source starts moving, it becomes more complicated to compute amount of water getting through the circle, since uniformness is lost, but amount of water that gets through the circle is still the same. This is why integral form of Gauss's Law is relativistically correct.

This intuition necessarily brings you to the point where you start questioning how fast water is supplied at the source. Well, you can think that water supplied instantly, this is what differential form (divergence) of Gauss's law says (or rather it relativistic correctness).

P.S. I agree that question should be part of Physics SE, but there is such a fine line (almost invisible) between Physics and Electrical Engineering.